# Remove space for item in gridew.builder flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-gridview

I am using Gridview.builder to show dynamic item count in a row with the help of crossAxisCount.
if crossAxisCount is 3 then 3 items are showing on grid. But It is showing top and bottom space(item space,not thein between space of items) for every item. Please help me how to remove the space. Thank you

code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Order extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _OrderState();
}

class _OrderState extends State<Order> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: GridView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 3),
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,

                itemCount: 9,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.red),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),

                    margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 20, 10, 10),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: const [
                        Text("hello"),
                        Text("hello"),

                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

screenshot:
[image]

[image]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Actually trying for this design

Comment: which space you remove in between two cards?

Comment: NO. internal space(container) of item

Comment: what do you actually expect, can you share any images?

Comment: @Jahidual I dnt want the space of top padding and bottom padding for text (hello -hello)

Comment: @kartheeki j you want this image I added in your question

Comment: You can apply this to Row  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start as requirement is still not  clear

Answer (score 0):

Try add `childAspectRatio`  in side `SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount()`:

```
             gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 3,
               childAspectRatio: 1/3
             ),
```

Comment: Internal space of item. Not the outer space

Comment: oh, try add `childAspectRatio: 1/3` in side SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount()

Answer (score 0):

The question is not so clear.

If problem is space between square, just remova `margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 20, 10, 10)`.

If problem is why your text in the center and look like container have space on top and bottom of the text, that's not the problem. Cause the `Grid` **item** was fixed sized of child (`Container`) and a `Row` inside, children of Row was fill the size of parent as default.

**Example**: just add alignment, the spaces is gone
[image]

**Updated**: update answer, check this example below

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: const [
              Expanded(child: Ticket(title: '#1', height: 200)),
              Expanded(child: Ticket(title: '#3', height: 400)),
              Expanded(child: Ticket(title: '#4', height: 300)),
            ],
          ),
        ]
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

class Ticket extends StatelessWidget {
  const Ticket({required this.height, required this.title, Key? key})
      : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  final double height;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(),
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(title),
            Placeholder(fallbackHeight: height),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it was moved to top then how to remove bottom space

Comment: But my items are not fixed size some times  items have diffrent data. So in this case which one I have to take. give some suggestions please

Comment: yes dynamic height per item but not staggered gridview look. 3 items in one row...next 3 in another row and so on.............

Comment: ok. will check with table

Comment: Added required image

Comment: I tried with row and column, but bottom space is showing because of dynamic height.  want to remove the bottom space

Comment: @kartheekij check updated answer

Comment: @kartheekij and please delete discussions chat, in next time, create a chat room.

Comment: why u given heights.  based on the webservice data the height will change. some times we have 12 items. some times the crossaxiscount will be 6.

Comment: @kartheekij cause it is an example i want to write short and fast, height represents the height of the child widget. You dont need passing height, just replace **height** by something like **Widget child**

Comment: @kartheekij please create a chat room to discussions, too many comment here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244794/discussion-between-kartheeki-j-and-tuan).

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, use `MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround` refer [`layout`](https://docs.flutter.dev/codelabs/layout-basics)

```
 Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: GridView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              crossAxisSpacing: 1,
              mainAxisSpacing: 1,
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            itemCount: 9,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.red),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: const [
                    Text("hello"),
                    Text("hello"),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: not working Ravindra. dynamic heights

Comment: what do you exact want can you add your wanted image?

Comment: Added wanted image